# Blender Cycles: baked texture Render black

Tags: texture-baking

as the title says, all my texture render as if there is no light. ive added planes w/ emissions, sun,spot ect. to no avail. im using blender 2.93 and a very low poly mesh. with a mixed shader (Diffuse and Glossy). here is what it produces.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to me like switched face Normal orientation ... you are baking inside of bag.

Comment: No ive even double checked by flipping faces

Comment: Please share your file via https://blend-exchange.com because it looks exactly like that ... btw did you selected Image texture node before baking?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vzgoj9Xw" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vzgoj9Xw/) here is the file. and yes i selected Image texture node before baking @vklidu

Comment: Thanks ... next time please insert code into your Q via edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your normals are oriented right, but your UVmap shares same place for outer and inner faces ... this caused your issue. You probably created models as single sided, unwrapped and added/applied Solidify = same UV for original unwrap and newly generated faces of Solidify.

You would have to separate them in some way ...

- fastest - just create another UVMap layer - unwrap as Smart UV Project and add Image Texture node with the same newly created image into each material

Comment: Thank you ill try that and update

Comment: Update:  Thank you vklidu, i removed the  Solidify unwrapped Smart UV and it worked perfect.